# Xcode save value of variable “before and after”

Tags: objective-c, variables, save

I currently have this code attempting to save the value of a specific variable in before, and then re-saving the new value of the variable a second later to a variable named after.

```
- (void)getAfter {
    after = Currentitems;
    NSLog(@"%d, %d", before, after);
}
- (void)detectItems {
    before = Currentitems;
    [self performSelector:@selector(getAfter) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}
```

The function "detectBPS" runs every second as well. However, both of the before and after variables equal the same thing. How can I achieve what I am attempting to do?

**Edit:** I've read the suggestions. However, how can I implement KVO? Nevertheless, I'd still rather use (and am more open to) different/simpler suggestions as well.

Comment: Save the before value wherever you change Currentitems.  Then it's actual vale becomes after.

Comment: @PhillipMills Can you show me an example?